# Turning system.drawing.drawing2d.graphics into .avi file?

Tags: .net, graphics, video-encoding

I have a .NET program that does some displaying by drawing on a system.drawing.drawing2d.graphics object. I'd like to be able to turn each "frame" drawn into a frame in an .avi file.

Are there AVI classes in .NET? Some simple way to get the bitmap that must underlie the graphics object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy enough to draw a bitmap in the same way that you are drawing on the graphics surface at the moment; an example of creating a graphics object from a bitmap can be found over on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404307.aspx). You could draw each bitmap image, display it on the graphics surface then write the bitmap to a file for later use.

A quick search also yielded [this codeproject tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/avifilewrapper.aspx) which has an example of generating an AVI from a set of bitmaps in C#.

Another example of this can be found in the [AVIWriter class](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/csharp/avi/write_avi.html).

Either of these examples could be modified to read your list of bitmaps generated in the drawing phase of your code and then generate the AVI.

Hope this helps!